How to translate point light and rotate directional light OpenGL?
I intend to implement Gouraud shading with two light.(point light and directional light)
I want to translate the point light and rotate the directional light with keyboard callback function of OpenGL.
But by my current code, light is not moving.
This is my main.cpp:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <GL/glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GL/glm/gtx/transform.hpp> // rotate(), scale(), translate()
#include <GL/glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <GL/glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

GLuint VertexArrayID;
GLuint programID;
GLint modelLoc;
GLint viewLoc;
GLint projLoc;
float sx = 0;
float sy = 0;
float sz = 0;
float translationStep = 0.1f;
float rotationAngle = 0.0f;
float rotationStep = 5.0f;
bool projMode = true; // true: perspective, false: ortho

GLint pointLightPosLoc;
GLint pointLightColorLoc;
GLuint directLightDirLoc;
GLuint directLightColorLoc;

glm::vec3 pointLightPos;
glm::vec3 pointLightColor;
glm::vec3 directLightDir;
glm::vec3 directLightColor;

GLfloat cubeVertices[] = {
    0.1f,  0.1f,  0.1f, // v0
   -0.1f,  0.1f,  0.1f, // v1
   -0.1f, -0.1f,  0.1f, // v2
    0.1f, -0.1f,  0.1f, // v3
    0.1f, -0.1f, -0.1f, // v4
    0.1f,  0.1f, -0.1f, // v5
   -0.1f,  0.1f, -0.1f, // v6
   -0.1f, -0.1f, -0.1f  // v7
};

GLfloat cubeColors[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Red
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Green
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Blue
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Yellow
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Magenta
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // Cyan
};

GLint cubeIndices[] = {
    //front
    0,1,2,
    0,2,3,
    //right
    0,3,4,
    0,4,5,
    //up
    0,1,6,
    0,6,5,
    //left
    1,2,7,
    1,7,6,
    //down
    3,7,4,
    3,2,7,
    //back
    5,7,6,
    5,4,7,
};

GLfloat cubeNormals[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // front
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // right
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // up
   -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // left
    0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // down
    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, // back
};

GLuint LoadShaders(const char* vertex_file_path, const char* fragment_file_path)
{
    //create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    //Read the vertex shader code from the file
    string VertexShaderCode;
    ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, ios::in);
    if (VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        string Line = "";
        while (getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    //Compile Vertex Shader
    char const* VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);

    //Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }


    //Read the fragment shader code from the file
    string FragmentShaderCode;
    ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, ios::in);
    if (FragmentShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        string Line = "";
        while (getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    //Compile Fragment Shader
    char const* FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);

    //Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }


    //Link the program
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(max(InfoLogLength, int(1)));
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}

void renderScene(void)
{
    //Clear all pixels
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Let's draw something here

    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    //define the size of point and draw a point.
    int numCubes = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; i++) {
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::vec3 translateVec(0.0f + sx, i * 0.3f + sy, 0.0f + sz);
        model = glm::translate(model, translateVec);

        glm::vec3 rotationAxis = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotationAngle), rotationAxis);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(cubeIndices) / sizeof(GLint), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }

    //Double buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void translationKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case 'q':
        sx += translationStep;
        break;
    case 'w':
        sx -= translationStep;
        break;
    case 'a':
        sy += translationStep;
        break;
    case 's':
        sy -= translationStep;
        break;
    case 'z':
        sz += translationStep;
        break;
    case 'x':
        sz -= translationStep;
        break;
    case 'o':
        printf("%d\n", pointLightPos.x); //temporary
        pointLightPos.x += translationStep;
        break;
    case 'p':
        pointLightPos.x -= translationStep;
        break;
    case 'k':
        pointLightPos.y += translationStep;
        break;
    case 'l':
        pointLightPos.y -= translationStep;
        break;
    case 'n':
        pointLightPos.z += translationStep;
        break;
    case 'm':
        pointLightPos.z -= translationStep;
        break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void rotationKeyboard(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        rotationAngle -= rotationStep;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        rotationAngle += rotationStep;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        directLightDir.y += rotationStep;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        directLightDir.y -= rotationStep;
        break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void setProjectionMatrix() {
    glm::mat4 proj;
    int width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    int height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    if (projMode) {
        // perspective projection
        proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    }
    else {
        // orthogonal projection
        proj = glm::ortho(-3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, -15.0f, 15.0f);
    }

    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));
}

void ProjecionModeMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        projMode = !projMode;
        setProjectionMatrix();
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void init()
{
    //initilize the glew and check the errors.
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s' \n", glewGetErrorString(res));
    }

    //select the background color
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //init GLUT and create Window
    //initialize the GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    //GLUT_DOUBLE enables double buffering (drawing to a background buffer while the other buffer is displayed)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);

    //These two functions are used to define the position and size of the window. 
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(480, 480);
    //This is used to define the name of the window.
    glutCreateWindow("Simple OpenGL Window");

    //call initization function
    init();
    //0.
    programID = LoadShaders("GVertexShader.txt", "GFragmentShader.txt");
    glUseProgram(programID);

    /**************************************************/
    // 모델, 뷰, 프로젝션 행렬을 셰이더에 전달
    modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "model");
    viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "view");
    projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "proj");

    // 뷰 행렬 설정
    glm::vec3 cameraPosition(5.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f); // 카메라 위치
    glm::vec3 targetPosition(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f); // 타겟(큐브) 위치
    glm::vec3 upVector(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // 업 벡터
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, targetPosition, upVector);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

    // 프로젝션 행렬 설정
    setProjectionMatrix();


    glm::vec3 pointLightPos(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
    glm::vec3 pointLightColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glm::vec3 directLightDir(-2.0f, -2.0f, -2.0f);
    glm::vec3 directLightColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // 점 광원의 위치, 색상을 셰이더에 전달
    pointLightPosLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "pointLightPos");
    glUniform3fv(directLightDirLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(directLightDir));
    pointLightColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "pointLightColor");
    glUniform3fv(pointLightColorLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(pointLightColor));


    // 방향 광원의 위치, 색상을 셰이더에 전달
    GLuint directLightDirLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "directLightDir");
    glUniform3fv(directLightDirLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(directLightDir));
    GLuint directLightColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "directLightColor");
    glUniform3fv(directLightColorLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(directLightColor));

    /**************************************************/
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    GLuint VBOs[3];
    glGenBuffers(3, VBOs);
    GLuint EBO[1];
    glGenBuffers(1, EBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeVertices), cubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLuint posAttribLoc = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "inPos");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttribLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttribLoc);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeColors), cubeColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLuint colorAttribLoc = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "inColor");
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttribLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLoc);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeNormals), cubeNormals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLuint normalAttribLoc = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "inNormal");
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalAttribLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalAttribLoc);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeIndices), cubeIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutKeyboardFunc(translationKeyboard); // translate cube and point light
    glutSpecialFunc(rotationKeyboard); // rotate cube and directional light
    glutMouseFunc(ProjecionModeMouse); // switch projection mode

    //enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    return 1;
}

And this is my GVertexShader.txt:
#version 400 core

in vec3 inPos;
in vec4 inColor;
in vec3 inNormal;

out vec4 vColor;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform vec3 pointLightPos;
uniform vec3 pointLightColor;
uniform vec3 directLightDir;
uniform vec3 directLightColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 vPos = vec4(inPos, 1.0);
    vPos = proj * view * model * vPos;
    
    vec3 tNormal = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * inNormal);
    
    vec3 pointLightDir = normalize(pointLightPos - vPos.xyz);
    float pointDiffuseStrength = max(dot(pointLightDir, tNormal), 0.0);
    vec3 pointDiffuse = pointDiffuseStrength * pointLightColor;
    
    float directDiffuseStrength = max(dot(-directLightDir, tNormal), 0.0);
    vec3 directDiffuse = directDiffuseStrength * directLightColor;

    vec3 reflectedLight = reflect(-pointLightDir, tNormal);
    float specularStrength = pow(max(dot(reflectedLight, normalize(vec3(0, 0, 1))), 0.0), 1.0);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * vec3(1, 1, 1);
    
    vColor = vec4(inColor.rgb * (pointDiffuse + directDiffuse) + specular, inColor.a);
    
    gl_Position = vPos;
}

...and GFragmentShader.txt:
#version 400 core

in vec4 vColor;

out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = vColor;
}

Maybe i think there are some problem with declaration and point uniform (e.g.'pointLightPos', 'directLightDir')
I try to print pointLightPos.x when keyboard 'o' is pressed. then result is random number.
Like below:
0
-1610612736
-1610612736
1073741824
-1610612736
0
1073741824
-2147483648
-1073741824
0
536870912
-1073741824
1610612736
0
-1610612736
1073741824

Help me to solve this problem.

Type of components of glm::vec3 is float. float has some layout in memory according to IEEE-754 standard. Because you used "%d" specifier in printf function you get decimal value of 4 bytes of memory area occupied by float variable. Use printf("%f") and you will see value you expect.
You don't update the uniform variable of the shaders program that means the position light (it should be done after each processed key events):
void translationKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    //...
    case 'o':
        pointLightPos.x += translationStep;
        printf("%f\n", pointLightPos.x); //temporary
        break;
    case 'p':
        pointLightPos.x -= translationStep;
        printf("%f\n", pointLightPos.x); //temporary
        break;

    // ....

    GLuint pointLightPosLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "pointLightPos");
    glUniform3fv(pointLightPosLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(pointLightPos));
    
    // update rest uniforms related to lighting
    
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

